# Error in PHP Login Code using mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have this Php Code for login checking. But When It succeesfully matches userid and password, it is OK. But when user name and password does not match in database, then it is only printing:

In isset

and Not printing sorry.

Code is here:

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'mysql.hostinger.in');
define('DB_NAME', 'u157309623_p2');
define('DB_USER', 'u157309623_p2');
define('DB_PASSWORD','nielit');

$db=@mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_error($db));

/*
$ID = $_POST['user'];
$Password = $_POST['pass'];
*/
function SignIn(mysqli $db)
{
session_start();   //starting the session for user profile page

    $query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT *  FROM UserName where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysqli_error($db));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query) or die(mysqli_error($db));
    if(!$row)
    {

        echo "SORRY";

    }
    else
    {
                echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN";

    }

echo "Not in Loop.";

}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo "in isset.";
    SignIn($db);
}
echo "Last Line.";

?>
```

Comment: what you want to do exactly??

Comment: it will echo 'in isset' because the submit button is clicked

Comment: He wants to `echo` "SORRY" if the row does not exist

Comment: First of all, you should read about SQL-Injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php, then to answer your question. Remove this code:  or die(mysqli_error($db));

Comment: replace  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query) or die(mysqli_error($db)); with if($query->fetch_array(){ echo 'success'; }else { echo 'sorry'; }

Comment: Why when user name and password not matching in database, it echoes only "in isset". It should echo "sorry" also. And also "not in loop", "last line". But it is stopping by printing "in isset".

Comment: Thank you PhpDev and Oliver. It is working.